# JUnit - How many files for testing a single class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Let's say I have a class `MyClass.java` and we have to write a tests for it. Some of them will execute once, some of them will execute multiple times.

1. I prepared two test classes - `MyClassTestSingle.java` for single tests and `MyClassTestMultiple.java` for tests with `@Parametrized` annotation.
2. I wanted to run them from a single file so there is another class - `MyClassTestSuite.java`.
3. In `MyClassTestSingle.java` and `MyClassTestMultiple.java` methods I use same parameters with a same values so i started thinking about a class containing these parameters...

But then I realized I wanted to create four classes for testing a single class. So I started looking for some "good practices" how to keep my test classes clean and simple. But found no worthy informations about number of classes I need when writing tests for a situation above.

I started thinking that maybe there is a design problem in my `MyClass.java`, but for sure there are situations when there is need to make a parametrized and single tests and then pack them into a suite.

Am I wrong? Or maybe I just don't understand something?

Comment: Parameterized test classes in JUnit are a pain; have you ever considered using TestNG and its `@DataProvider`s instead?

Comment: Also, what about the code of your `MyClass`? Using parameterized tests makes sense in some scenarios but not all; if you "start[ed] thinking that maybe there is a design problem" then you may want to post the code of `MyClass` instead, and if not possible, something very similar to it, and explain what you want to test.

Comment: @fge No, I haven't. I didn't even know that there are more valued testing frameworks for Java code. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: For the record: your question is really on the edge of regarding "opinion-based" answers.

Comment: @fge The class is not ready yet. When you asked me for a code I realized all the tests can be executed in a `@Parametrized` class. But I still think that there may be a situation where a knowledge how to act will be valuable.

Comment: @fge Or go straight to Spock!

Comment: @GhostCat Well, didn't mean that. I will pay more attention to this next time.

Comment: @chrylis not sure what you mean here; you mean Spock as the testing framework?

Comment: @fge Yes. Among many other benefits, it makes parameterized testing extremely clean and easy.

Comment: @chrylis if you say so... I have never had the incentive to use Spock to test pure Java code. IIRC Spock is written in Groovy, right?

Comment: @fge Yes, Spock is written in Groovy and makes extensive use of AST transforms to provide a more declarative API. I tend to write polyglot Java and Groovy anyway, but it's easy to make Spock just a test-scope dependency for a pure-Java-runtime project. (Advantage skyrockets if Selenium is involved and you can use Geb.)

Comment: @chrylis I can only take your word for it... My programming scope is limited to pure data exchange and I've never had to use Selenium :) Still, I retain what you said in a corner of my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "right" or "wrong" way here. However there are some conventions.

First, typically test cases names are typically ended by `Test`. Typically we implement test case per class and name it after the production class with `Test` suffix. Follow this convention and various build and reporting tools will work for you automatically without additional configuration.

Splitting test case to several classes can be used if it is needed. For example when number of tests or number of code line exceeds reasonable limit or if there are some test groups that should be maintained separately. Your example (parameterized and not parameterized tests) sounds like reasonable case.

So, I'd create `MyClassSingleTest.java` and `MyClassMultipleTest.java`.

Variants: 
`MyTest.java` and `MyTestParameterized.java`.

Probably a good idea to give more meaningful name. Try to express what do your parameters mean. For example `UserParameters`, `DbParameters` etc. In this case call your parameterzied class `MyClassUserTest.java` or something like that.

Comment: When specs are split up, it is sometimes helpful to name the classes something like `MyClass_FooTest` and `MyClass_BarTest`.

Comment: While it is my general experience and my experience is limited, I find the fact that you have to write several test classes for a same class a design flaw; more often than not, it means that you may have to split the logic of the SUT (System Under Test). But again, that is my limited experience only.

Comment: I tend to agree, having to split your test case is at least a code smell and could point to the fact that your class is too complex and/or does to much, which would be solved by splitting the class, not the test.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, in some cases you are right. However sometimes the class does a lot of things not itself but using delegation.

Comment: That's why I think it's a so called 'code smell'. A code smell just can, but doesn't have to, be something bad. It's something worth having a look at, just to check if it's ok, but not something automatically bad